# Can java-script be use via a browser to write a file

Tags: javascript, html, file, browser

Does java script have the functionality to write files to the local machine?

Description: i working on a project that would allow java-script to generate some content and then store it as a text file to my PC.

Description two: i'm also interested in have the java-script read in a text page and store that as a text/html file on the local machine.

I've been searching for a while but unable to find any function that would allow java-script to read and write files. any suggestion ? ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13405129/javascript-create-and-save-file

Comment: no such thing call `java-script`.

Comment: javascript . . . happy now

Answer (score 0):

The Answer of your question is simple "NO" because of security issues and breaking the sandboxing rules via script could be written so You can access local machine via Javascript !

Comment: Would the answer not be "YES" depending of security settings of the zone you are using?

Comment: Let say scripts runs on server ... how can u change security settings of every users browsers so it might not be fruitful to change settings for only your  browser because eventually you would want to run your script on server if i'm not wrong ! At last you have to use libraries